# Как статично сформировать таблицу (datagrid) в xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Во всех примерах только показано их источников, я хочу сам задать значения. Как это сделать?

Comment: — Я случайно полную бутылку колы.

— Ты случайно что?

— Полную бутылку колы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[украдено](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739357/is-it-possible-to-make-an-liststring-a-static-resource-in-xaml)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="persons" Type="{x:Type local:Person}" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication146">
        <local:Person FirstName="Sarfaraz" LastName="Nawaz"/>
        <local:Person FirstName="Prof" LastName="Plum"/>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="MyLittleTable" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource persons}}"/>
</Grid>
```

в xmlns:local нужно заменить не ваш неймспейс на ваш.

Невероятно, но:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```